# Calling WCF services in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, prism

I am working on a Prism desktop application and would like to know the best way to deal with lookup / reference data lists when using a WCF backend. I think this question may cover a few areas and I would appreciate some guidance

For example, consider a lookup that contains Products(codes and descriptions) which would be used in a lot of different input screens in the system.

1. Does the viewmodel call the WCF service directly to obtain the data to fill the control?
2. Would you create a control that solely deals with Products with its own viewmodel etc and then use that in every place that needs a product lookup or would you re-implements say a combobox that repopulates the products ItemsSource in every single form view model that uses it?
3. Would I create a brand new WCF service called something like LookupData service and use that to populate my lookup lists? - *I am concerned I will end up with lots of lookups if I do this.*
4. What other approaches are there for going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating your lookup object/component as a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) object for WCF service. It can work in several ways, but most simple coming to my mind would be:

1. Implement WCF service with methods to provide **all** `Products` entities and requested one (eg. basing on product code)
2. Implement component that will use WCF client to get products, let's call it `ProductsProvider`
3. Your view models will take dependency on `ProductsProvider` (eg. via [constructor injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection))

Key element in this model is `ProductsProvider` - it will work as kind of cache for `Products` objects. First, it will ask web service for all products (or some part of it, up to your liking) to start with. Then, whenever you need to lookup product, you ask provider - it's provider's responsibility to deal with how product should be *looked up* - maybe it's already in local list? Maybe it will need to call web service for update? Example:

```
public class ProductsProvider
{
    private IList<Product> products;
    private IProductsService serviceClient;

    public ProductsProvider(IProductsService serviceClient)
    {
        this.serviceClient = serviceClient;
        this.products = serviceClient.GetAllProducts();
    }

    public Product LookUpProduct(string code)
    {
        // 1: check if our local list contains product with given code
        // 2: if it does not, call this.serviceClient.LookUpProduct
        // 3: if service also doesn't know such product:
        //    throw, return null, report error
    }
}
```

Now, what this gives you is:

- you only need to have **one** `ProductsProvider` instance
- better flexibility with when and how your service is called
- your view models won't have to deal with WCF at all

**Edit:**

As for your second question. Control may not be needed, but having view model for `Product` entity is definitely a good idea.